# github pages showing old project in new repo

Tags: github, github-pages

Trying to upload a complete new project to github pages.
When I completely deleted the old code, and uploaded my new dist folder to the repository, I still see my old page.

I visited `https://<name>.github.io/index.html`, and back to `https://<name>.github.io/`
I deleted the repo, created a new one with the same name. Uploaded my new files. I still see my old project.
What can I do to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to clear your browser cache? And may you need to wait some time while your project was updated by GitHub

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to either create one with a completely new name or wait for a few hours since it could take time for it to completely get deleted